# change color of li on hover

Tags: css, menu, hover

I want to change color of a li element on hover,

```
<ul id="sitemap">
        <li><a href="#">a</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">e</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
            </ul>                   
        </li>
</ul>
```

here is the css code :

```
 #sitemap li:hover{
    background:#eee;
}
```

When I hover on any child li of a i.e b,c.. f   it also changes background color of parent(a). How can I change the bg-color of only current li element on hover, there can be li at 3rd level also so what could be the general solution..

Answer (score 3):

Simply add `ul` to your selector, and it will be fine

```
#sitemap ul li a:hover {
  background:#eee;
}
```

The reason it wasn't working before is because it was targeting the top level `li`, so everything below it was apart of that `li`. Therefore, when the submenu was hovered, all of the block was highlighted

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5PXk/3/)

Comment: You missed the part about **there can be `li` at 3rd level also so what could be the general solution..**

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Yeah I did miss that part. The updated answer does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add > into your css so that it has to be a direct descendant.

```
#sitemap ul > li > a:hover {
  background:#eee;
}
```

For more information check out http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors